# How to open a webView from assets, by switchcase function?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have 10 cardview in a fragment, when user click on one it'll open a specific html file within the application. When I try to open this class, the apps always crash .

[My MainActivity is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM3yE.jpg)

[2nd Activity is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXNV.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include the code in your images, and add the stacktrace for your crash to your question

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to solve your issues is, in your MainActivity's onclick method change like :

```
Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.indonesia_card:
                i = new Intent(this, Indonesia.class);
                i.putExtra("isFrom", "Indonesia");
                startaCtivity(i);
            case R.id.mathematika_card:
                i = new Intent(this, Indonesia.class);
                i.putExtra("isFrom", "Mathematika");
                startaCtivity(i);
            case R.id.ipa_card:
                i = new Intent(this, Indonesia.class);
                i.putExtra("isFrom", "IPA");
                startaCtivity(i);
        }
```

Now, In your other Activity receive the intent and set data appropriately.

```
String from = getIntent.getStringExtra("isFrom");
        if (isFrom != null) {
            if (isFrom.equals("Indonesia") {
                webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
            } else if (isFrom.equals("Mathematika") {
                webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
            }else if (isFrom.equals("IPA") {
                webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help you.